# Juju lxd bridge profile

Tags: juju

I was trying the Juju deployment to lxd container 
example:

```
juju deploy --config testconfig.yaml example-my-charm --to lxd:1
```

It created the container on the machine 1 but failed to deploy the charm. This is due to the bridge `lxdbr0`. I have 2 interfaces defined on machine 1. I will need to modify the lxd profile, so that it can connect to the internet.

The question here is, can I send in the lxd profile configuration via juju like the `testconfig.yaml`, or do I have to first pre-configure machine 1 with lxd brigde profile before doing juju deployment? (Note: Doing one machine is ok, but if I have 100 machines it will be an issue)

Comment: what type of cloud are you using?

Comment: Trying to deploy Openstack using juju.

Comment: Is there a way for juju to provision the lxd container command with the following setting
1) add new profile or change the default profile with 2 or more bridge interface
   example:
 devices:
    name: eth0
    nictype: bridged
    parent: lxdbr0
    type: nic
  eth1:
    name: eth1
    nictype: bridged
    parent: lxdbr0
    type: nic

2) Set the static IP address for eth0 and eth1

Thanks